# Using Enterprise Validation Application Blcok with MVC 3 and ObjectValidator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, enterprise-library

I'm trying to use the enterprise application block with mvc 3 and am getting a problem with complex objects. I my situation I have an example like below:

```
public class MainClassType{
    [ObjectValidator]
    public SubClassType SubClass{ get; set; }
}

public class SubClassType{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The class "MainClassType" is in my view model, but whenever I hit the submit button, the model binder kicks off some validation which throws the error below:

```
A validation attribute of type ObjectValidatorAttribute cannot be used to validate values
```

Any ideas whats goign wrong here?

Matt

Comment: Just as an update - I think its related to this thread: http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/211051?ProjectName=entlib